# Conversion failed on String to Date time

Tags: sql-server

I must calculate time between several dates, but this fields are not date type, this fields are varchar, so I must convert them. 
For example I have this values:

```
CODIGO  SUMILLA_HDR1        SUMILLA_HDR2
N050044 07/01/2015 10:58    09/01/2015 12:32:36
N050044 07/01/2015 10:58    09/01/2015 11:58:10
```

If I convert the value with the sentence:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(8), CAST('07/01/2015 10:58:38' AS DATE),112)
```

I have: 20150701      => this is fine for me.

But If I try the next:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(8), CAST(SUMILLA_HDR1 AS DATE),112) 
FROM FLUJO_CS
WHERE CODIGO = 'N050044'
```

I have the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I don't know why is this, the values are the same, anybody can help me please?
It will be appreciated.

Comment: What sql-server version are you using? This works for me in my 2008 R2 version. Also what is your language settings?

Comment: You probably have incorrect data in table

Comment: And what is your default language ? Spanish ?

Comment: Thanks John, Version:Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)

Comment: and languaje : English (United States). But It is not our server, I don't know if I must change language because there are other applications on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted value with this:

```
CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), SUMILLA_HDR1),103)
```

For example, If I want number days from a date, I have this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), SUMILLA_HDR1),      CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), SUMILLA_HDR1),103),
DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),      SUMILLA_HDR1),103)) 
FROM FLUJO_CS
WHERE CODIGO = 'N050044'  
AND SUMILLA_HDR1 IS NOT NULL
```

Thank you!!
best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you have rows with corrupted data. The values are not the same. In table you have time without seconds. Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(8), CAST(SUMILLA_HDR1 + ':00' AS DATE),112) 
FROM FLUJO_CS
WHERE CODIGO = 'N050044
```

'

Comment: thanks Giorgi, Those are same values, but it seems when I copied and pasted them, seconds were ommited, but in database are the same values

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert the date:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(char(50), '07/01/2015 10:58:38',112) AS DATE)
```

Casting a date as string (without convert) can result in different date format depending on the user's language settings.